# Bean ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository missing error for WebClient Oauth2 Openid service to service connection

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I want to make service A to service B connection.
Service B is protected by OAuth2.

Hence i want to use webClient to do client id / credential authorization.

Below is my configuration code

```
@Bean
ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository getRegistration() {
    ClientRegistration registration = ClientRegistration
            .withRegistrationId("keycloak")
            .tokenUri(tokenUri)
            .clientId(clientId)
            .clientSecret(clientSecret)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
            .build();
    return new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(registration);
}

@Bean(name = "keycloak")
WebClient webClient(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations,
                    ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClients) {
    ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth =
            new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(clientRegistrations, authorizedClients);
    oauth.setDefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClient(true);
    oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("keycloak");
    return WebClient.builder()
            .filter(oauth)
            .build();
}
```

dependency i used shown as below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And application properties i used

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri=https://<domain>/auth/realms/<realm_name>
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.authorization-grant-type=client_credentials
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.provider=keycloak
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-id=<>
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-secret=<>
```

However, I met this problem when I start my spring boot application

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem, try this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and this:

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
```

Comment: Can you explain why this dependency can answer to the question ? Please [edit] your post